# header function not working in php after setting session

Tags: php, session

so i have creted this php where if session is set do this and if it isn't set than go to another php so my code goes like this

```
 <?php
ob_start();
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && !empty($_SESSION['id']))
{
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
    if(isset($id))
    {
        $connection=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','123456789','register');
        $query="select email from register where id='$id'";
        $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $email=$row['email'];
    }
}

else {header('location: best.php');}
?>
```

even if i opened this page directly without setting session i am still able to visit and doesn't get redireccted to best.php page how to deall with this problem

Comment: why the ob_start(); ? I think its part of your problem, do you have any need of buffering ?

Comment: You probably want your php script to bail out after the header(location....) instead of going on  with printing the "normal" page contents.

Comment: what actuallt prob are you facing as i have copied you code and pasted in my editor it redirect to best.php while i have not set the session and stay on test page if have set the session before

Comment: Just tested this...works fine from mySIde...done

Comment: You might have set the session already, so when you open this page directly, you will not be redirected since session is available. To check, close your browser and reopen it, then run this, you will be redirected successfully

Comment: well thanks MyWay when i reopen my browser it works fine